# What can be done so far with cloud quantum computing?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, superconducting-quantum-computing

As a developer myself, I still do not understand what can be done so far with services like [AWS BRAKET](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/introducing-amazon-braket/) or [IBM CLOUD QUANTUM COMPUTING](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/technology/experience).
Can someone explain me the practical purpose of it in the present? Or is it mostly a PR move to create hype?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are resources to help people get started with learning about quantum computing. They are also useful to help further research as services such as IBM Q Experience provide access to real quantum computers, and so people can conduct research using them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, makes sense.